# count zero occurrences by choosing randomly

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have following list with some values, which I retrieved from a json file:

```
def read_json(object):
    categories_list = []
    object=json.loads(object)  
    for feature in object['features']: 
        categories = feature['properties']['category_ids']
        for category_Id in categories:
            categories_list.append(category_Id)

     pois = np.array(categories_list)

return pois
```

Then I am catching pois and saving it to listA:

```
listA = read_json(json_object)

listA= [u'156' u'204' u'426' u'488' u'426' u'570' u'488' u'564' u'426'  u'208' u'476' u'566' u'429' u'395' u'570' u'280' u'570' u'108' u'395' u'426' u'570' u'208' u'280' u'426' u'449' u'108' u'570' u'395' u'192' u'204' u'570' u'569' u'156' u'192' u'518' u'192' u'570' u'469' u'395' u'426' u'566' u'156' u'208' u'561' u'449' u'518' u'208' u'280' u'280' u'430' u'566' u'203' u'566' u'570' u'280' u'570' u'570' u'108' u'518' u'570' u'564' u'516' u'280' u'426' u'569' u'280' u'570' u'566' u'426' u'564'u'570' u'485' u'395' u'108' u'570' u'391' u'395' u'280' u'192' u'566']
```

Now I am choosing randomly 10 values from listA with following numpy method:

```
subsample = np.random.choice(listA, 10, replace=False)
```

the Output for`subsample` is:

```
[u'204' u'566' u'570' u'206' u'570' u'570' u'518' u'561' u'192' u'570']
```

an then I am counting same values, and saving it to a dictionary

```
unique, counts = np.unique(subsample, return_counts=True)
group_cat =dict(zip(unique, counts))
```

output of `group_cat`:

```
{u'204': 1, u'206': 1, u'561': 1, u'570': 4, u'566': 1, u'192': 1, u'518': 1}
```

However my aim is to count all zero occurrences, which are in listA as well. My output should look as following:

```
{u'204': 1, u'206': 1, u'561': 1, u'570': 4, u'566': 1, u'192': 1,
u'518': 1, u'395':0, u'429':0, u'108':0, u'564':0, ....}
```

How can I save all not selected values in my dictionary as well?

Comment: Please make sure the code and data you put in is executable. Part of our answering workflow is usually to test the answer to make sure it is correct; if we can't do that easily, many people will give up on your question as too much hassle, and you're losing potential answerers. `listA` is missing commas, we have no clue what `pois` is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
listA= [u'156' u'204' u'426' u'488' u'426' u'570' u'488' u'564' u'426'  u'208' u'476' u'566' u'429' u'395' u'570' u'280' u'570' u'108' u'395' u'426' u'570' u'208' u'280' u'426' u'449' u'108' u'570' u'395' u'192' u'204' u'570' u'569' u'156' u'192' u'518' u'192' u'570' u'469' u'395' u'426' u'566' u'156' u'208' u'561' u'449' u'518' u'208' u'280' u'280' u'430' u'566' u'203' u'566' u'570' u'280' u'570' u'570' u'108' u'518' u'570' u'564' u'516' u'280' u'426' u'569' u'280' u'570' u'566' u'426' u'564'u'570' u'485' u'395' u'108' u'570' u'391' u'395' u'280' u'192' u'566']

subsample = np.random.choice(listA, 10, replace=False)
uniques, counts = np.unique(subsample, return_counts=True)
dictA = {e:0 for e in listA}    
for unique, count in zip(uniques, counts):
    dictA[unique] = count
```

Or even simpler :

```
listA= [u'156' u'204' u'426' u'488' u'426' u'570' u'488' u'564' u'426'  u'208' u'476' u'566' u'429' u'395' u'570' u'280' u'570' u'108' u'395' u'426' u'570' u'208' u'280' u'426' u'449' u'108' u'570' u'395' u'192' u'204' u'570' u'569' u'156' u'192' u'518' u'192' u'570' u'469' u'395' u'426' u'566' u'156' u'208' u'561' u'449' u'518' u'208' u'280' u'280' u'430' u'566' u'203' u'566' u'570' u'280' u'570' u'570' u'108' u'518' u'570' u'564' u'516' u'280' u'426' u'569' u'280' u'570' u'566' u'426' u'564'u'570' u'485' u'395' u'108' u'570' u'391' u'395' u'280' u'192' u'566']
dictA = {e:0 for e in listA}    
subsample = np.random.choice(listA, 10, replace=False)
for e in subsample:
    dictA[e]+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following list comprehension:

```
zero_occurences = [e for e in pois if e not in unique]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **`dict.fromkeys`** which creates a new dictionary from the given sequence of elements with a value (optional).

Later, use `update` method to update the created dictionary with `counts`.

```
subsample = np.random.choice(listA, 10, replace=False)

unique, counts = np.unique(subsample, return_counts=True)

group_cat = dict.fromkeys(listA, 0)
group_cat.update(zip(unique, counts))

print(group_cat)
```